# Refactoring update fuction in a basic Elm app

Tags: elm

I've recently started with Elm and I run into a problem with the update function. My goal is to split up my big [Main.elm](https://github.com/mdvanes/elmsta/blob/master/app/Main.elm) file into multiple smaller files, but to do this I first try to split up the main components into smaller components in the same file. For this I rely heavily on [this very informative guide](https://medium.com/@_rchaves_/structured-todomvc-example-with-elm-a68d87cd38da).

It is fairly straightforward to split the Model and init (which I already did for DiceRoller) and it is trivial for the View. Not so much for the Update unfortunately.

Currently, it looks like this (in the master branch of the [Main.elm](https://github.com/mdvanes/elmsta/blob/master/app/Main.elm) file)

```
type Msg = Change String
    | Name String
    | Password String
    | PasswordAgain String
    | Roll
    | NewFace Int
    | SearchImages
    | NewSearchResult (Result Http.Error (List String))
    | ChangeTermInput String

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Change newContent ->
            ({ model | content = newContent }, Cmd.none)
        Name name ->
            ({ model | name = name }, Cmd.none)
        Password password ->
            ({ model | password = password }, Cmd.none)
        PasswordAgain password ->
            ({ model | passwordAgain = password }, Cmd.none)
        Roll ->
            (model, Random.generate NewFace (Random.int 1 100))
        NewFace newFace ->
            ({ model | diceRoller = { dieFace = newFace} }, Cmd.none)
        SearchImages ->
            (model, getSearchResult model.termInput)
        NewSearchResult (Ok newResult) ->
            ( { model | termResult = newResult }, Cmd.none )
        NewSearchResult (Err _) ->
            (model, Cmd.none)
        ChangeTermInput term ->
            ({ model | termInput = term}, Cmd.none)
```

And I managed to get it a bit more refined, but this does not compile (also see [this Main.elm in the refactoring branch](https://github.com/mdvanes/elmsta/blob/refactoring/app/Main.elm)):

```
type DiceRollerMsg = Roll
    | NewFace Int

type Msg = Change String
    | Name String
    | Password String
    | PasswordAgain String
    | MsgForDiceRoller DiceRollerMsg
    | SearchImages
    | NewSearchResult (Result Http.Error (List String))
    | ChangeTermInput String

updateDiceRoller : DiceRollerMsg -> DiceRoller -> DiceRoller
updateDiceRoller msg model =
    case msg of
        Roll ->
            model
        NewFace newFace ->
            { model | dieFace = newFace}

updateDiceRollerCmd : Msg -> Cmd Msg
updateDiceRollerCmd msg =
    case msg of
        Roll ->
            Random.generate NewFace (Random.int 1 100)
        NewFace newFace ->
            Cmd.none

updateCmd : Msg -> Model -> Cmd Msg
updateCmd msg model =
    Cmd.batch
        [ updateDiceRollerCmd msg
        , getSearchResult model.termInput
        ]

updateModel : Msg -> Model -> Model
updateModel msg model =
    case msg of
        Change newContent ->
            { model | content = newContent }
        Name name ->
            { model | name = name }
        Password password ->
            { model | password = password }
        PasswordAgain password ->
            { model | passwordAgain = password }
        MsgForDiceRoller msg ->
            { model | diceRoller = updateDiceRoller msg model.diceRoller}
        SearchImages ->
            model
        NewSearchResult (Ok newResult) ->
            { model | termResult = newResult }
        NewSearchResult (Err _) ->
            model
        ChangeTermInput term ->
            { model | termInput = term}

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
    (updateModel msg model, updateCmd msg model)
```

It fails to compile with a type mismatch on the line Role in updateDiceRoller, because the pattern matches DiceRollerMsg, but it is trying to match Msg. If I just change the input and return types to DiceRollerMsg I get: Function `updateDiceRollerCmd` is expecting the argument to be: DiceRollerMsg But it is: Msg

Also I do not think that Cmd.batch in updateCmd is the best solution here.

I appreciate any input to making a better Elm app, also outside these questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compile errors originate from using `Msg` as input and return values for `updateDiceRollerCmd` while the case statement is using `DiceRollerMsg`. You can fix this function by pattern matching from, and mapping to, `MsgForDiceRoller`.

```elm
updateDiceRollerCmd : Msg -> Cmd Msg
updateDiceRollerCmd msg =
    case msg of
        MsgForDiceRoller Roll ->
            Random.generate NewFace (Random.int 1 100)
                |> Cmd.map MsgForDiceRoller

        _ ->
            Cmd.none
```

There is one more compile error in your view where you will need to change `onClick Roll` to `onClick (MsgForDiceRoller Rool)`

Comment: Wow, they were not kidding about the efficiency of the Elm community, thanks! I had no idea about those mappers and definitely did not expect that it would be possible and needed to cast in the onclick.